# '+systemFontSize:' not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

`Method '+systemFontSize:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`
`'UIFont' may not respond to '+systemFontSize:'`

Searching Google for the exact phrase doesn't get any results, relevant or not. The nearest I've found was someone else having a different problem with `label.font = [UIFont systemFontSize:12.0];` as the solution. That's what I'm trying to do now, but Xcode is yelling at me about it.

If it matters, I'm using this book: [Professional iPhone and iPad Database Application Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470636173)
I'd be surprised if it does, but there you go.

Comment: I think you're looking for `systemFontOfSize:`

Comment: @Moshe I put the tag (like this), [not like this], for my convenience and for that of anyone else who looks at the title before the answer count and the color of that number. Easily noticeable as (my edit), as opposed to an [automated edit]. It's more efficient for the mentioned group and there is no harm done to others. Deleting that bit was completely unnecessary.

Comment: I agreed there was no real harm done by adding solved to the title but I'll back up @Moshe since it is not generally how things are done (and it is good to keep an order) selecting an answer as correct is enough, the system has its built in method show the questions is solved (as you know http://i.imgur.com/W443Q.jpg) Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `systemFontOfSize:`, not `systemFontSize:`.  So, you'd set it this way:

```
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

Comment: @Thromordyn: It's not a stupid mistake, I've done it myself before.  They look so similar, it's easy to leave out the `Of`. :)

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation for UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You're probably looking for `systemFontOfSize:`, note the "Of".